# Typescript: dynamically constructing property name on type

Tags: typescript

Surely this is rudimentary TS, but I can't find the syntax.

I have a type:

```
type MyType = {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: string;
}
```

Now inside a function I have a variable of type MyType, but I need to dynamically get the value 
of a particular property on it, like:

```
const myMethod = (typeX: MyType, num: number) => {
    const property1 = typeX['prop${num}`]; // problem line!
}
```

The typescript error I'm seeing is:

```
TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyType'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'
```

Changing it to `typeX['prop1']` works fine.

How do I cast that string as a property on MyType?

Comment: I think changing it to `typeX['prop1']` makes it statically analyzable to the compiler, and it's recognizing the property as being valid.

Comment: What happens if you type `typeX['invalid property']`?

Comment: Interesting, you're correct - I get the same error with an invalid property. Seems like there should be a way to calm down the TS parser and just cast it somehow?

Comment: `((any)typeX)['prop${num}']`?

Comment: I get a `'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here` with that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do casts in TypeScript, refer to the language spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a type assertion here (similar to a cast in other languages but with no runtime semantics):

```
type MyType = {
   prop1: string;
   prop2: string;
}

const myMethod = (typeX: MyType, num: number) => {
    const property1 = typeX[`prop${num}` as keyof MyType]; 
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAWQgFWvAvHA3qOeoBOA9lAIwBccAzmAQJYB2A5gNy77FQBMlN9zbEAF9QoAMZEGNOAFsICGGAAWRACZxMACkiwAGpSSpYAGjgMArjMoWZAIxgEAlBoB82dnglSwcQiQeQpBpwOjC6ANoABn5QACRYNkKRcACGVHAA1jAQRABmiChoALoscKBCQA)